# Not getting Parse.com notifs on android Device

Tags: android, eclipse, cordova, push-notification, parse-platform

I have made a basic **android app using phonegap 2.7.0** in eclipse. I want to **send push notifications** on the device **using parse.com**.

**I have looked for other posts here for help and they don't address this specific issue.**

I have **followed the guide** on http://www.raymondcamden.com/2012/10/10/PhoneGap-Parsecom-and-Push-Notifications . I can see that my page at parse.com has 1 recipient while sending push notifications which means that **my app has successfully subscribed to parse.com**. I can also send push notifications from parse.com and the status of these notifications say Done. But I am **not receiving these notifications on the android emulator** even when I have internet connection on the emulator.

My Android MainActivity.java is as follows

```
package com.example.parsetrial;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;
import org.apache.cordova.*;
import com.parse.*;

public class MainActivity extends DroidGap {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        //setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        super.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/index.html");
        Parse.initialize(this, "Application ID", "Client Key"); 
        PushService.subscribe(this, "", MainActivity.class);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

My Android Manifest file is as follows

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.parsetrial"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="18" />


     <supports-screens 
    android:largeScreens="true" 
    android:normalScreens="true" 
    android:smallScreens="true" 
    android:resizeable="true" 
    android:anyDensity="true" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_LOCATION_EXTRA_COMMANDS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CONTACTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" /> 
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BROADCAST_STICKY" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

        <service android:name="com.parse.PushService" />
<receiver android:name="com.parse.ParseBroadcastReceiver">
   <intent-filter>
      <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
      <action android:name="android.intent.action.USER_PRESENT" />
   </intent-filter>
</receiver>

        <activity
            android:name="com.example.parsetrial.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Please help me get notifs on my emulator. Only after this I can test this app on a device.

**EDIT:**

Tried running on an actual device with Google account and internet. Still the same issue. I can see the number of recipients increase after I install the app in the new device. But I still don't get push notifs. **Please Help...**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to configure your emulator to target Google API then you have to log in with your Google account on your emulator.

Otherwise, emulators don't have Play Services and don't have registrationId for GCM.

Comment: Thank you for your flash response but I have a couple of questions.
1. Will the problem get solved by adding a Google account on the emulator? Or by testing the app on an actual device which has Google Play services? 

2. How to configure emulator to target Google API? Also that I am not using anything like GCM in my code or app.

PS-I am new to this and don't know anything about GCM

Comment: If you don't know how to configure your emulator, the easiest solution is to test it on a real Android device. GCM (Google Cloud Messaging) is the service used by every push SDK to provide rich push on Android. Parse is using it without you knowing about ;)

Comment: As you mentioned, I tried running it on an android device. Even parse.com showed that another recipient was added. But when I sent push notifs from parse.com, I still didn't get any notifs on the device(even after waiting for 30mins). Status of those notifs on parse.com says Done. Device has an android account and is connected to a high speed WiFi connection so network is not a problem.